# How much did Hayden Christensen actually appear in the Obi-Wan Kenobi series?

Tags: star-wars, darth-vader, obi-wan-kenobi-2022

There was quite a lot of excitement and promotion around the return of Hayden Christensen's Anakin Skywalker to the Star Wars universe in the *Obi-Wan Kenobi* series.

Of course, all of this is muddled by the fact that in the present day of the series, there is little of Anakin left and mostly all that remains is Vader, who, conveniently is usually completely suited.

Now, this [link](https://www.cheatsheet.com/entertainment/obi-wan-kenobi-three-different-actors-playing-darth-vader-suit.html/) among others explains that Vader was played by three performers:  Christensen, Dmitrious Bistrevsky, and Tom O’Connell.  And, in addition, Vader is voiced by James Earl Jones.

So, I am interested in how many seconds of Christensen we actually get.

Ideally, this should be broken down by episode, whether the appearance is on-screen or voice-only, and which appearances are new vs. reused (e.g. from the Prequel Trilogy) footage.

For the purpose of this question, absent any other evidence, I think we can assume that an appearance of a fully-suited Vader is not Christensen, or it can be considered "inconclusive".  At the very least during action scenes it is most likely not Christensen.

Comment: I surprised they didn't think they could get a better performance out of David Prowse.

Comment: @DavidW "David Prowse obituary | Movies | The Guardian" https://amp.theguardian.com/film/2020/nov/29/david-prowse-obituary

Comment: @FuzzyBoots That's the joke.

Comment: "how many seconds of Christensen there really is”- really?

Comment: One thing I can say is that they should have used some de-aging techniques on Hayden.  Him playing Anakin didn't look quite right.

Comment: It's even more confusing - this is growing evidence that James Earl Jones is only credited as a courtesy, and his voice is computer synthesized, like they did Luke's in a lot of The Mandalorian.

Comment: @VBartilucci:   Well, if the AI model was trained on his performances then it's reasonable to credit him.

Comment: Oh, absolutely, and I'm sure he got a paycheck, as he should.  but sings point to him not having done much, if any actual studio time.

Comment: @VBartilucci:   I mean, why would this be?   Is he not healthy enough or his voice not robust enough anymore?

Comment: Same reason they did it for Mark Hamill - he's older, and his voice doesn't sound quite the same as it did back then.  Jones' voice was certainly weaker in Ep 3, and that was years ago.

Answer (score 5):

Ignoring Darth Vader in the suit, and based on your link provided, Hayden Christensen spent:

- Approximately 72 seconds in the Kenobi-Skywalker duel flashback in episode 5.
- Approximately 13 seconds in Reva's Order 66 flashback in episode 5.
- Approximately 17 seconds in the bacta tank scene in episode 2
- Approximately 12 seconds in Obi-Wan's nightmare in episode 1.

This totals to 114 seconds across the season, ignoring occasional repeats of the same footage (so multiple times showing the duel flashback does not increase the Christensen time count for the purposes of this answer)

Please note that these were all figured by checking time stamps, so they are all approximate, hopefully accurate to within 5 seconds.

Comment: Ooh — how about Obi-wan's vision of Anakin when he and Leia are walking on Mapuzo, before they hitch a ride?

Comment: Oh, forgot about that one... I'll edit my answer once I can get those seconds counted. Thanks, @PaulD.Waite