# Which actor has played the same sci-fi character for the longest time?

Tags: actors

[News articles like this one](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/entertainment-arts-63032248) are stating that James Earl Jones is looking to wind down his career, and has supposedly given permission for Disney to use artificial intelligence and archival recordings to recreate his voice in the future.

Jones first played Vader in Star Wars in 1977 and most recently, his voice was used in the 2022 Obi-Wan Disney+ series. This is a time period of 45 years.

Has any other actor in a sci-fi production played the same role for a longer period of time? This can include both live-action and voice work.

The only caveat I would place on this would be that the actor must have been alive when the role was played, but they can have died before the material was published.

I've looked at some *Doctor Who* actors (as the longest-running sci-fi TV show) and have been unable to find anyone with a similar length of service:

- Carol Ann Ford (Susan Foreman, Dr. Who, 1963-1993) - 30 Years
- Elizabeth Sladen (Sarah Jane Smith, Dr. Who, 1973-2011) - 38 Years

---

**EDIT**: The following contenders have been suggested via various answers:

- Noel Neill - Lois Lane (Superman) - 1948-2013 - 65 Years
- Jack Larson - Jimmy Olsen (Superman) - 1952-2013 - 61 Years
- William Russel - Ian Chesterton (Dr Who) - 1963-2022 - 59 Years
- Carole Ann Ford - Susan Foreman (Dr Who) - 1963-2021 - 58 Years
- William Shatner - James T Kirk (Star Trek) - 1966-2019 - 53 Years
- George Takei - Hikaru Sulu (Star Trek) - 1966-2019 - 53 Years
- Leonard Nimoy - Spock (Star Trek) - 1966-2013 - 47 Years
- Tom Baker - The Doctor (Dr Who) - 1974-2021- 47 Years
- Ysanne Churchman - Alpha Centauri ( Dr Who) - 1972-2017 - 45 Years
- Majel Barrett - Computer (Star Trek) - 1966-2009 - 43 Years
- Paul Naschy -  Count Waldemar Daninsky (Various) - 1968-2004 - 36 Years

Comment: Yes it's from the date of their first performance until the date of their last performance.

Comment: Outside SF, there's a voice actor who [played the same character from 1951 to 2022](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/entertainment-arts-62462139) (i.e. 71 years), before finally retiring at the age of 103. So SF has some catching up to do!

Comment: Does it count if they first did radio, then advanced to play the same character on TV?

Comment: I did think [Ghostbusters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghostbusters) might be in with a shout, because the characters (minus one) return in [Ghostbusters: Afterlife](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghostbusters:_Afterlife). But from 1984 to 2021 is "only" 37 years. Honourable mention, but doesn't beat the OP's baseline numbers.

Comment: Werewolf honorable mention https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Naschy

Comment: @GEdgar - yes as long as it is the same character

Comment: Patrick Stewart for Jean Luc Picard has been 45 years (1987-2022) which will go into 2023 I believe for 46 years.

Comment: @iMerchant That's 35 years, not 45.

Comment: @Graham Maybe years count double after you're knighted. :)

Comment: What about contiguous "density" -- e.g. Tom Baker played Dr. Who for the most years continuously, as opposed to making one appearance in 1963 and another in 20-something?

Comment: I probably wouldn't define someone playing a role once, and then playing it again 30 years later as "playing the same character for 30 years". Noel Neill, for example, seemingly didn't play Lois Lane for 55 years during those 65 years which she played Lois Lane (and she also played someone *other than* Lois Lane, and plenty of other people have played Lois Lane, within Superman media during that time). But narrowing down what exactly it would constitute playing the same character for some period of time may not be that straightforward and this may be arguing semantics.

Comment: @NotThatGuy the whole point is to argue semantics. Arguing syntax would be a waste of time.

Comment: I'm pretty sure William Shatner has not played Kirk since Generations in 1994, so much less time than 53 years, 1966-2019. Rather 28 years. Any other roles have either not been played by Shatner, or have been Shatner appearing in documentaries or unofficial non-canon pieces.

Nimoy, on the other hand, is a pretty good contender if we allow a brief reprisal over a decade after his last role.

Comment: Burt Ward played animated Robin in 2017 and in 2019 on the Arrowverse Crises on Infinite Earths.  Adam West dying just before the 2017 Batman vs. Two Face was released putting them both longer than the original Star Trek cast also starting in 1966.

Comment: **Note**: I updated the title after OP accepted the answer that had the longest span. The previous title was a yes/no question, and every one of the answers was an implicit "no".

Comment: Editing the answer into the question just feels wrong to me. Usually, one simply clicks the check mark on the accepted answer and if folks want other info, they read through some/all the answers. But, maybe things are different here at SF&F...

Comment: @BrianC argue about it on the answer, not the question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Superman franchise has two contenders.

[Noel Neill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noel_Neill#Filmography) played Lois Lane in the [*Superman*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superman_(serial)) serials in 1948, and reprised the role in [*Superman and the Secret Planet*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6573122/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_2) in 2013. That's 65 years.

[Jack Larson](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0489001/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t36) is not far behind, first playing Jimmy Olsen on the [Adventures of Superman](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0044231/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_12) TV series in 1952 (along with Neill), and also appearing in *Superman and the Secret Planet*.

They also appeared as Lois and Jimmy Williamson in 2016's [Surge of Power: Revenge of the Sequel](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1989632/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_1)<sup>*</sup>. The last names are different, but these characters are obviously homages to their signature roles.

<sub>* I haven't seen it, but this this cast has lots of minor roles by well known genre actors, including: Linda Blair, Gil Gerard, Lou Gerrigno, Nichelle Nichols, Marina Sirtis, Walter Koenig, Richard Hatch, Nicholas Brendan (the last few playing themselves).</sub>

Comment: Even if you want to disqualify fan-made work, Larson returned as Jimmy Olsen in Lois and Clark in 1996, which is a healthy 42 year run.

Comment: @VBartilucci I started my search by looking for cameos on Smallville, but they didn't  show up there, so I suspected I was confusing it for Lois & Clark.

Comment: I wonder if "Williamson" was an homage to the legendary SF author Jack Williamson.

Answer (score 52):

If you extend from film and TV to audio plays, Carole Ann Ford has been playing Susan Foreman for **58 years**:

- [Dr Who: An Unearthly Child](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0562828/releaseinfo?ref_=tt_dt_rdat) (1963)
- [Dr Who: After the Daleks](https://www.bigfinish.com/releases/v/doctor-who-after-the-daleks-2229) (2021)

William Russel is close behind. His last audio performance as Ian Chesterton was released in 2020.

There's every chance either may make a cameo appearance in the anniversary specials next year, cementing them with 60 years on TV in the same role.

---

Edit: William Russel just appeared in [Dr Who: The Power of the Doctor](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt15243958) (2022), so is currently at **59 years** in the same role on the same TV series.

Comment: According to https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/After_the_Daleks_(audio_story), After The Daleks was recorded in 2019, so Carole Ann Ford has played Susan for 56 years. It would be interesting to find out when William Russell last played Ian Chesterton as it might be close between the two

Comment: @A.Steer [It's unlcear](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Susan's_War_(audio_anthology)?so=search#Notes), but the question is concerning release dates, not recording.

Comment: Tidbit, but there was a pic. of Susan in the 50th anniversary show, if that would count.

Comment: @Zenzizenzizenzic - a pic of Susan was also used in the first episode of the last series of Peter Capaldi's Doctor -- he has it on his desk at the university, alongside a pic of River Song.

Comment: I saw a news article that said William Russell has a Guinness Book of World records for longest character now.

Comment: @lucasbachmann well that's not true unqualified. William Roache has been playing Ken Barlow since 1960.

Comment: Rumours abound that Carole Ann Ford will be reclaiming her top spot soon.

Answer (score 47):

In keeping the with SF&F aspect: Leonard Nimoy played Spock over a period of ~47 years. From his initial appearance in the original *Star Trek* TV series in 1966 to *Star Trek: Into Darkness* in 2013.

Depending on how strict you're being this is *slightly* beaten by his *Star Trek* colleague William Shatner as archival recordings of him playing James Kirk are used in the 2019 episode of *Short Treks*  "Ephraim and Dot", which would take his career as Kirk from 1966 to 2019 or 53 years.

Comment: I completely forgot about Star Trek. With Spock being in the pilot, I suspect he will be the longest character and actor combination. I will leave it 48 hours to see if anyone else comes up with anything, but I think you have got it.

Comment: On a similar note, Majel Barrett played the computer for 43 years.

Comment: @OrangeDog And was supposed to have continued playing the computer, using the same technology they're using on SW, tho I believe they've not done it - unsure why.

Comment: But Majel Barrett was not playing the same computer the whole time.

Comment: George Takei would match Shatner, if archival footage was included as they are both in the Man Trap (Series 1 Episode 1) as well as Ephraim and Dot

Comment: Both Shatner and Takai were also in Where No Man Has Gone Before, which chronological is the first episode of the season proper to be filmed. Which was around 6 months before The Man Trap

Comment: Nimoy as Spock also appeared posthumously in *Star Trek: Beyond* in 2016, though only in a photograph.  Still, he's in the credits, for whatever that's worth.

Comment: Majel Barrett appeared as "Number One" in _The Menagerie_ in November 1966, in scenes taken from the unaired pilot. She also appears as "Number One" in the Discovery episode _An Obol for Charon_ in February 2019 in a blink-and-you'll-miss it homage to TOS and _The Cage_. I don't know if that counts.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman If included posthumous apparences,  Leanard Nimoy as Spock,James Doohan as Scotty and Nichelle Nichols as Uhura appeared in Startrek: Prodigy via archived audio from various sources in the episode "Koboyashi" from 6 Jan 2022, I'd expect these would be credited.

Answer (score 34):

Since Jones was only supplying a voice, it might be fair to mention the large number of voice actors who played the same role for many decades.

For example:

- Mel Blanc voiced Bugs Bunny from 1940 until his death in 1989.
- Don Messick voice Ranger Smith in the Yogi Bear cartoons from 1959–1994, and Scooby Doo from 1969 to 1997.
- Frank Welker has voiced Fred Jones (from Scooby Doo) from 1969 till today.

I could also mention that ALL the surviving actors from *Star Wars* have been playing their roles for the same time period as Jones. Mark Hamill has played Luke the most recently, so he'd be tied with Jones in that one film alone.

Comment: Mark Hammill's last "appearance" was in The Book of Boba Fett, while Jones was in Obi-Wan, so Jones wins by about 6 months.

Comment: @DaveJohnson Anthony Daniels would be just about tied with Jones, and Daniels was in the Threepio suit for most of his live-action appearances as well IIRC.

Comment: As this answer steps outside the sci-fi realm, note the example raised by @SteveMelnikoff above of June Spencer from The Archers who trounces all of them with 72 years, retiring this year.

Comment: @DaveJohnson Technically [Jones wasn't actually in Obi-Wan](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/267182/13024).

Comment: @OrangeDog the question specifically lists it when determining the timeframe

Comment: @DaveJohnson the question incorrectly assumes he was actually performing in Obi-Wan, and that it wasn't already an AI reconstruction.

Comment: they've not (AFAIK) been 100% clear if Jones provided any new work for Obi-Wan which they used as a base, as Hamill did.  He's credited because they used his voice as the base data, and I expect that will remain so in future projects. I hope he keeps getting paid as well.

Comment: @OrangeDog you incorrectly read the question to assume that it incorrectly assumes he was in it. It clearly states that Jones's "voice was used" in Obi-Wan. The OP included it in his question criteria regardless.

Comment: @StackerLee Interesting that you should mention The Archers (BBC radio soap). Ysanne Churchman, who was in it until the mid-fifties, supplied the voice of Alpha Centauri in Doctor Who in 1972, and reprised the role twice - most recently in 2017, which is 45 years.

Comment: Upvoting for mentioning Frank Welker... that man has an absolutely enormous portfolio.

Comment: Daniels has a credit in a couple of 2022 releases. I'm not sure if either of them are after Obi-Wan Kenobi though.

Comment: The question was asking specifically about actors who played **sci-fi** characters. Looney Tunes, Jogi Bear and Scooby Doo can hardly be categorized as Sci-Fi.

Comment: Since we're talking about voice actors, and Mel Blanc was mentioned, I'd like to honor [June Foray](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/June_Foray) Perhaps best known for Rocket J Squirrel, she had _many_ other characters. Notably, [Granny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granny_(Looney_Tunes)) (the owner of Tweety in Warner Bros cartoons): 1955-2011 (56 years).

Comment: Surely Marvin the Martian and Duck Dodgers in the 24th and a half century count as sci-fi :-)

Answer (score 19):

Returning to Dr. Who, I haven't seen a mention of the Fourth Doctor [Tom Baker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Baker) yet.

Baker was "The Doctor" from 1974 to 1981, but later appeared as the Fourth Doctor in a 1993 special, and has played the role in several radio adaptations, the latest being in 2021 -- a span of 47 years.

Comment: Don't forget he featured ons creen in the 50th anniversary special in 2013! A very on the nose cameo for 'the Curator'.

Comment: @CrazyDino to be ultra literal - the Curator is the x+4 doctor - who just happens to be exactly like the 4th doctor from some arbitrary x number of regenerations in the future we will never see on screen.

Answer (score 8):

Additional - if we want to stick to sci-fi, the actors on the various Japanese *tokusatsu* shows have made recurring appearances on the respective franchises for 50-plus years.

Hiroshi Fujioka who played Takeshi Hongo in the original *Kamen Rider* series in 1971 has returned to reprise the role as recently as 2021 for the **50**th anniversary of the franchise.

Kenji Ohba, who has played lead (on camera) roles on several series (and suit actor in many more) has returned to play said characters, including *Space Sheriff Gavan* (1982), in many specials and films, playing Gavan again as recently as 2017.

Bin Furuya, who was the suit actor for the original *Ultraman* series **55 years ago**, returned to be body-scanned and motion-capture work for the CGI version of the character in the new film *Shin Ultraman*.

Answer (score 8):

Anthony Daniels is still doing voice acting work for C-3PO, most recently in [*Obi-Wan Kenobi* and *Lego Star Wars Summer Vacation* TV shows and the *Lego Star Wars: The Skywalker Saga* video game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthony_Daniels) in 2022. As of 2020, he was saying that he would ["never retire"](https://screenrant.com/star-wars-anthony-daniels-c3po-future-updates/) from playing C-3PO. I would think that means he's going to be beating James Earl Jones more or less by defintion?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  While it's possible that he _may_ pass JEJ, he hasn't yet, and that wouldn't yet beat some of the others on this list anyway.

Comment: I suppose it depends on the precise release dates of Daniel's 2022 releases vs Obi-Wan Kenobi. I don't have time to check those details right now.

Comment: Lego Star Wars Summer Vacation was released 5th August 2022, the final episode of Kenobi came out 22nd June 2022. Daniels pips Jones by around six weeks.

Comment: @DavidW:  (copy of my comment on OP's question):  What about contiguous "density" -- e.g. Tom Baker played Dr. Who for the most years continuously, as opposed to making one appearance in 1963 and another in 20-something? –

Answer (score 1):

Shuuichi Ikeda (Char Aznable) and Toru Furuya (Amuro Ray) have been reprising their voice actor roles from *Mobile Suit Gundam* since 1979. Most recently, they both appeared in the 2022 movie *Mobile Suit Gundam: Cucuruz Doan's Island*.

I'm throwing their names out here for completeness' sake since they're still active and have an appearance density on par with the *Star Wars* and *Star Trek* actors.

Comment: Note that 43 years is less than most of the other examples here, and less than the example asked in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Counting voice acting? Adam West, Burt Ward, and Julie Newmar. All started playing the characters of Batman, Robin, and Catwoman in 1966, and all three reprised their roles in the 2016 animated film *Batman: Return of the Caped Crusaders*, and the 2017 *Batman vs Two-Face*, giving all three 51 years.

Ward went on to play Dick Grayson in a brief scene in the first episode of the CW Arrowverse's "Crisis on Infinite Earths" crossover on *Supergirl*, giving him 53 years between his first and last live-action version of the character.